# How to ignore NDepend issue?

Tags: ndepend

What is the recommended approach to ignore a NDepend issue or rule violation? Modify the query in the NDepend config file, or is there a better approach?

Just wondering that starting to add ORs in the CQLinq query isn't maybe the nicest thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2018 we plan to support SuppressWarning attribute.

For now you can either modify the rule as you wrote, or also use the [JustMyCode/notmycode approach](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-syntax#NotMyCode) to avoid issues on particular code elements.